# Installing Pysnap

Tags: python, package, pack, snapchat

I'm trying to install the [Pysnap](https://github.com/niothiel/snapchat-python) package for Python.

The website says to run "python setup.py install" using setuptools. I've tried installing setuptools but it just doesn't seem to work.

So how do I install the package?

SOLUTION: Worked after running "setup.py install" instead of "python setup.py install"

Comment: What does "it just doesn't seem to work" mean?  You needtotellus.

Comment: it is not a proper Python package. There is a [pull requests that tries to make it so](https://github.com/niothiel/snapchat-python/pull/3)

Answer (score 0):

[Go to this link](https://github.com/martinp/pysnap/archive/master.zip) and unzip the package, then put it in your LIB folder in your python installation

Answer (score 0):

When you download and use python you are recommended to install a few other 'features' setuptools and pip are the most common. Depending on your IDE, I recommend using PyCharm as it automatically installs those for you. As for installing Pysnap package you must cd to your directory where setup.py is found and type in

```
python setup.py install
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If setup requires setuptools, install pip by saving [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) python file then running it.
Pip relies on setuptools so the installation will take care of it for you. All you have to do now is download the framework as a zip from Github, extract it, and use the command line to run `python setup.py install`.